# Periodically running docker command?

Tags: docker

I need to run the following 2 commands very often (maybe once a day for example):

`` docker exec -t my_db pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > dump_`date +%d-%m-%Y"_"%H_%M_%S`.sql ``

`docker exec -t my_db pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > latest_backup.sql`

How would I do that though? The docker container will be deployed to production and I want to take backups of the database. I read up on cron, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can trigger a pg_dump through docker using a cron job but if you are using an Orchestrator it would be preferable to rely on the task schedulers they provide.

See for example for OpenSift : [Cron Jobs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html), for Kubernetes : [Cron Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/), if you're using Rancher : [Container crontab](https://github.com/rancher/container-crontab), etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Sébastien said, [Container crontab](https://github.com/rancher/container-crontab) is suited if you use rancher. Install the stack and add a label 'cron.schedule=* * * * * *' on your service.

If your not using any orchestration tool, [mcuadros/ofelia](https://github.com/mcuadros/ofelia) is a nice little container that is able to schedule commands (exec, run) on your existing containers. It also has some nice logging features like email reports or slack messages.